# TV with small diagonal (32") without 4K resolution? Is that still up to date?

Tags: monitors, television, hdtv

I am looking for a TV 32". I do not want an Android TV, my preferred OSes are Tizen and webOS.

When I filter for 32" TV I don't find any that support 4K. It come in several online stores only 1080p tv.

Is there a specific reason for this? I thought 4K was standard today (2023)?

Comment: 4K panels are being mass produced in larger sizes like 40+ inches diagonal. Originally it was just easier to make bigger 4K panels and more profitable because the yield of successful panels was higher. Compressing the pixels to fit in 32" means much lower success rate and that means less profit. The 32" 4K panels are just starting to become mass produced in the past few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heared of such thing (because the market for small TVs has died down) but there are monitors that size in 4K and smaller, which can be used as a TV, although they don't come with "smart" TV features, you need something like an Nvidia Shield or Apple TV for that to work

Comment: Do you know why? What is the reason? ---> "because the market for small TVs has died down"

Comment: @Sybil, The prices of TVs have come down enough that people with a fixed budget can now buy TVs that are several inches larger for the same price today. A long time ago a 32" TV was the biggest you could get for X dollars. Now it's more like 42" for the same X dollars. That is why the market for small TVs has died down. Most people who want small TVs now only want them specifically for the size and not because they're cheaper.

Comment: thanks @Romen. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

a 32" TV, even at 1080p, can be difficult to view from a distance, as a TV (not computer monitor) should.

I've bought a 32" TV @ 1080p rather than the 720p; if I were to do it again I would get the 720p because it is a TV I am not less than 3 feet from it like a computer monitor.

A 32" @ 4K would not be good as a TV.

32" @ 4k is good as a computer monitor, if you face is less than 2 feet from it, and is good visually for gaming and video watching.

So yes a 32" **TV** sold at stores having less than 4K resolution is *still up to date*.

The 32" 1080p TV I bought, viewing from couch ~10 feet away, I cannot read the directv stream guide channel nor much of the Roku channel listings.  If that were 4K resolution it would be horrible.